# Free replacement for PGP Desktop

Tags: encryption, pgp, pgp-desktop

A few years ago I used to use PGP Desktop unfortunately Symantec bought this excellent program and now wants a lot of money for Symantec Encryption Desktop Professional. Does anybody know of a free replacement for this  software that offers encrypted virtual disk functionality. I can use bitlocker if I want whole disk encryption but  I'd rather have an encrypted file that I can move about and simply mount it when I need to access the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.truecrypt.org/

This tool can (amongst other things) "Create a virtual encrypted disk within a file and mount it as a real disk."

You will obviously need to have the TrueCrypt software on any machine on which you want to access the content of the encrypted file container, but a portable version is available and for various platforms.